# How to create a form with input type file in moodle

Tags: moodle

I am new to moodle. I am  trying to create a new form with input type file element but it is not creating properly.

Here is my trying code :

```
   $mform->addElement('file','csvfile', get_string('File'));

    $mform->setDefault('Upload a CSV File', get_string('defaultuploadfile'));
    $mform->addRule('Upload a CSV File', get_string('missingfile'), 'required', null);
    $mform->setType('file', PARAM_MULTILANG);
```

but the output is look like below :

```
[[File]] (Max size: 750MB)   browse nofile selected
```

how to solve this issues

Comment: can you please explain me how to create custom  from in moodle

Comment: Please  Refer to this  https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=195430   also   check   this    https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Form_API   @ user3663

Answer (score 0):

For detailed information you should look at [Form API for Moodle](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Form_API) and [Using the File API in Moodle forms](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Using_the_File_API_in_Moodle_forms)

My suggestion is, that you should write something like that, if you want to upload `.csv`:

```
$mform->addElement('filepicker', 'userfile', get_string('file'), null,
                           array('maxbytes' => $maxbytes, 'accepted_types' => '*'));
$choices = csv_import_reader::get_delimiter_list();
            $mform->addElement('select', 'delimiter_name', get_string('csvdelimiter', 'newmodule'), $choices);
            if (array_key_exists('cfg', $choices)) {
                $mform->setDefault('delimiter_name', 'cfg');
            } else if (get_string('listsep', 'langconfig') == ';') {
                $mform->setDefault('delimiter_name', 'semicolon');
            } else {
                $mform->setDefault('delimiter_name', 'comma');
            }

            $choices = core_text::get_encodings();
            $mform->addElement('select', 'encoding', get_string('encoding', 'newmodule'), $choices);
            $mform->setDefault('encoding', 'UTF-8');
```

Comment: If we use filepicker means how to set validation into my files and can you explain your example please